# Show that R[x]/(x^7 +1) is not an integral domain.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I know that I am to use the thm. R/A. is a integral domain iff A is prime.
So I want an case where for some a,b in R and ab in A we have a nor b in A.

I thought it had something to do with the conjugate, but I'm lost.

Comment: $x^7+1=(x+1)(x^6-x^5+x^4-x^3+x^2-x+1)$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What would be "the conjugate", since you do not know what ring $R$ you are dealing with?

As suggested in the comments, $x^7+1=\underset{a}{(x+1)} \underset{b}{(x^6-x^5+x^4-x^3+x^2-x+1)}$. Neither $a$ nor $b$ are in the ideal $A=(x^7 + 1)$, since all nonzero elements there have degree at least 7, but their product $ab$ is in $A$. Hence $A$ is not prime.

Answer (score 0):

The ring is an integral domain if and only if the ideal is prime. The ideal is prime if and only if the polynomial is irredicible, and you can see that $x^7 +1$ is not either by finding an explicit factorization into smaller degree polynomials, or by noting that if it were irreducible, then $\mathbb R[x]/(x^7+1)$ would generate a degree $7$ field extension of $\mathbb R$ which is impossible, because the only finite field extension of $\mathbb R$ with degree $> 1$ is $\mathbb C$, which has degree $2$. This uses the fundamental theorem of algebra.